# Change LinkedList to accept Objects instead of Int?

Tags: c++, c, oop, pointers

I have a fully working LinkedList that functions with int variables. I'm looking to change it work with objects,  but I'm feeling stuck when it comes to pointers. Any advice?

This is the Node struct:

```
   typedef struct Node
{
   int data;
   Node* next;
 }*   nodePointer;
```

And this is the AddNode function:

```
void LinkedList::addNode(int dataToAdd)
{
  nodePointer nodeToAdd = new Node;
  nodeToAdd->next = NULL;
  nodeToAdd->data = dataToAdd;

  if(head != NULL)
  {
    current = head;

   while(current->next != NULL)
   {
   current = current->next;
   }

    current->next = nodeToAdd;
  }//end if

  else
  {
     head = nodeToAdd;
   }//end else
}//end addNode
```

Is it a matter of a few simple changes?

Comment: What are you having trouble with exactly? Change `int data` and `int dataToAdd` to whatever object type you want to store would be a first step (you might want to start investigating templates, also).

Comment: I concur.  The new declarations would look like `someObjectType data` and `someObjectType dataToAdd`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the type of objects you will be using.

For any class where the default `=` operation makes sense, you could use the same code you have right now, replacing `int` with your object's type.

For a more complicated object (for instance, one holding a pointer to a dynamically allocated member), you would have to either define an appropriate `=` operator for this class or use a copy function to ensure that the object is properly copied